# Function with parameter. RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working with functions and arguments and even with a simply code when function is called inside I'm getting error like:  line 7, in question
if ask == 'yes':
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

If I type in: Yes in answer, yes it works fine but when I type in: no and function is called belowe else statement I get error:
line 5, in question
if ask == 'yes':
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

I'm doing something wrong?
BTW I googled the problem and doesn't solve problem sys.setrecursionlimit(5000) and still getting error:

```
ask = input("Are you OK?:").lower()
asked = ask
def question(n):

    if ask == 'yes':
        return n

    else:
        question(n)

print (question(asked))
```

I tried another way:

```
def question():
    ask = input("Are you OK?:").lower()
    if ask != 'yes':
        question()
    else:
        return ask


print(question())
```

But in this code it works only if I answer 'yes' straight away, if I answer first time 'no' it ask again as expected and when second time I answer 'yes' it returns and prints: NONE.

Comment: if `ask != 'yes'` then the function will just call itself indefinitely (or until max recursion depth is exceeded).

Comment: I see it now :-)
However when I put question inside the def question()  and do print(question()) something strange is coming, when I type in in answer Yes it works but when  'No' it asks again and when I answer 'yes' returns NONE.

Answer (score 0):

`question()` is asking a new question in each call. `print(question())` just concern the answer from the **first** question. When you type `No` for your **first** question, `question()` is called asking the **second** question, and return `None` to your **first** question. Any answers after that just ask new question `if ask != yes` or return result to that question `if ask == yes` but do not affect the `None` return in **first** question.

Instead of keep asking new question, you can use while loop to keep asking new answer for the same question until the condition is met:

```
def question():
    ask = input("Are you OK?:").lower()
    while ask != 'yes':
        ask = input("Are you OK?:").lower()
    return ask

print(question())
```